# Event firing before data is actually set [Testnet]

Tags: web3js, events, ropsten, rinkeby, kovan

Today I've faced the behavior similiar to this post. 
[Event firing before data is actually set](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/event-firing-before-data-is-actually-set)

I'm getting events using infura and then checking for the state. I expect to read updated blockchain state according to the fired event. But I always get the old state.

In the post above changing to public testnet solved the problem.
I've tried Ropsten, Kovan and Rinkeby testnets. The same behavior everywhere.

What happened? Is blockchain broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using different nodes. Web socket for listening events(infura) and http provider for reading the state (metamask). Changing to websocket both solved the problem.